# Is there an API to change the PowerPoint slide show window background color from black?

Tags: vba, winapi, slideshow, powerpoint

When a PowerPoint presentation is run in a slide show window that is not the same aspect ratio as the presentation design, black bars appear at the top and bottom or left and right (depending on the window size). For example, when presenting a 16:9 deck on to a 4:3 display, black bars appear above and below the content.

I am trying to change the default color from black.

The VBA object model for SlideShowWindows does not appear to have a property to do this.

I have checked the Win API for SetSysColors (user32.dll) and this doesn't appear to affect the slide show window background color either.

Is there a way to override this color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to change the black bars that appear in this situation.

Comment: Gutted :-( but shared with the original requestor on LinkedIn : https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Can-you-change-framing-bars-1797044.S.5904854068001521665

Comment: You might remind them that black bars will make the bars less apparent on a projected image than any other color will.  Black is Good!  An alternative that just occurred to me:  Use my Resize add-in (www.pptools.com) to resize the presentation to the size of the screen/display it'll be presented on.  This will leave PPT background to either side or top/bottom rather than the PPT-imposed black bars.  You could then reformat the background to any color you like.  Photofills. Textures.  Gradients. Go mad!